# How to resume a logic app workflow with an HTTP call

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I created an Azure Logic App triggered by an HTTP call. Basically, this would be a workflow that would require some manual interventions. For example, someone ask for a day off, then someone else must approve it (this is a really basic example, but we can imagine that more form will be used for more advanced workflows).

For that, I created an angular application that trigger the logic app. From the HTTP trigger, I could return workflow information, including its run ID.

Now I'd like to add another HTTP trigger (or something else) that could resume that specific workflow instance (maybe using this ID). I found information about web hook but it's really not clear to me how to use it. Is it the correct way to do or is there a better way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing can be accomplished with a WebHook, but...then you have to manage the callback state in the UI app.  That's just making things unnecessarily complicated.

Is the state of the business process stored elsewhere?  SQL Database/Table?

In instead of having one Logic App to manage this process, you can have several that do the work for individual steps.